# Is it correct to say "If you changed your mind"?

Tags: grammar, future-constructions

I want to know if the following sentences are correct:

- If you changed your mind tomorrow, call me then.
- If it was open tomorrow, buy another one for me.
- If it was closed the next week, forget it forever.
- I will see you tomorrow if you also were there.

Answer (score 3):

All your sentences are wrong, it should be:

> If you **change** your mind tomorrow, call me.
>
> If it **is** open tomorrow, buy another one for me.
>
> If it **is** closed next week, forget it forever.
>
> I will see you tomorrow if you **are** there.

Future present tense requires a present tense, therefore you cannot use any past tense.